# Remove sine wave sound from wave file

Tags: java, audio, javasound

Basically I have one wave file that as some audio messages mixed with a loud beep, that I suspected is a sine wave sound generated.
My questions are:
It's possible to remove this beep, or somehow filter it using java?
I already tried applying some low level and high level filters, but with no sucess...

Comment: You can use digital filtering, but it's complicated.

Comment: It might be possible to 'add' (subtract) a sine wave of the same frequency and see what happens. But you'd have to do it iteratively, probably, until you arrive at the phase value that causes cancellation or near cancellation. But that is a really low tech and iffy way to go, and not anything I ever actually attempted. There are new commercial sound tools that can pull out voices or instruments from a mix. I haven't priced them, though. Am curious how precise the notch filters on Audacity can be. That free tool might suffice.

Answer (score 0):

A sine will be a single very specific frequency. An extremely narrow bandpass filter centered on that frequency would do a lot to mute it. Cutting it out entirely would require knowing *EXACTLY* what frequency it is.

What I'd do would be fire up my copy of SoundSoap, let it learn on a sample or two of the beep, and have it do all the work. But that's a commercial product.